# From a list of dicts, get a number N of dicts with highest values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, max

I have a list of dicts that looks like this:

```
dict = [{'skill': A, 'importance': '4'}, {'skill': B, 'importance': '6'}, {'skill': C, 'importance': '5'}]
```

I would like to get the **two** keys with the highest values (two most important skills)

The result should be:

```
['B', C']
```

I was able to get the maximum skill (B) with:

```
most_important = max(dict, key=lambda x:x['importance'])
```

but I don't know how to specify more than one maximum, or an **N number** of maximums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find multiple maximums -> sort and take biggest N.

```
sorted(dict, key=lambda x:x['importance'])[:2]
```